# How to create session object and session variables in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, session, object, session-variables

How do I create session object in jsp?
seems like  a silly question but what is the difference between seesion variable and session object?
And can anyone show me how to create session variables and how do I retrieve the value of the variables?

Comment: Hi! This is a very basic question and can be easily searched and get very good results in Google (or in your favorite search engine). Also buy Head first Servlets and JSP it is very good book for beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session` is an implicit object in jsp. you need not to create it. Container does it for you.
session variable means a variable which is pointing to a real object. 
1. Creating variable(reference)  is different thing(we use class type before the variable(reference) creation)
2. Creating object is different thing(we use `new` keyword for object creation)

and then we have to assign object created in step 2 to step 1 by using = symbol.

```
UserClass refUser = new UserClass(); // UserClass is some class for example.
```

right side of the = symbol is object creation process
and left side of = symbol is variable(or reference) creation.

## ReadHeadFirstCoreJava